# Display months rather than days on a graph X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I have 2 graphs that share the same X axis and are plotted on a single figure (i.e. one X and two y axis). The problem is that a time frame, shown on the shared X axis is overly detailed and displays days rather then months(which I would prefer).

```
[fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Months')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color=color)
ax1.plot(df\['2019'\]\['Price'\], color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('RSI', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(RSI(df\['2019'\]\['Price'\]), color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()][1]
```

Expect X axis to display months rather than dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `DateFormatter` function and apply it on the x-axis data.
I have created a solution using some sample data, replacing RSI with a "Sales" information.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Sample Data
data = [['2019-03-20',10, 1000],['2019-04-04',22,543],['2019-11-17',13,677]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Price','Sales'])

# DateFormatter object to use abbreviated version of month names
monthsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Months')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color=color)
ax1.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True), df['Price'], color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Sales', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True), df['Sales'], color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

# Apply X-axis formatting at the end
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)

fig1.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This leads to the following result:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: In addition you would probably want to use a `MonthLocator()` to make sure the ticks are actually all at the start of the month. (Else some date like 2019-04-29 would still be labelled April)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xticks` method, to set the locations and labels of the ticks in your graph. As an example:

```
plt.xticks( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Note that the first list is the **locations** of the ticks on the axis, and the second is the labels. From the attached image, it is impossible to understand the type or scope of your x-axis, but I hope the solution is.